# Travis CI: Run branch conditional script

Tags: yaml, travis-ci

I am working in a .NET Core project. I have the following `.travis.yml` file. This works well, but I want to have a `https://dev.mysite.co.uk` environment.

Anything merged into the `develop` branch, I want to end up on `https://dev.mysite.co.uk`, but anything merged into the `master` branch, I want deployed to `https://www.mysite.co.uk`.

```
language: csharp
mono: none
sudo: required
dist: xenial
dotnet: 2.2
branches:
only:
    - master
    - develop
before_script:
- chmod -R a+x scripts
script:
- "./scripts/docker-publish-travis.sh"
after_success:
- "./scripts/after-success.sh"
notifications:
email:
    on_success: never
    on_failure: always
```

How do I add a conditional to the above `.travis.yml` file so that if the branch is `develop`, a different script is run?

**develop branch**

```
script:
    - "./scripts/docker-publish-travis-develop.sh"
```

**master branch**

```
script:
    - "./scripts/docker-publish-travis-master.sh"
```

I did [find this](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/conditional-builds-stages-jobs/) in the docs, but I'm not sure how that would fit if I don't use stages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the page you referenced may complicate things for you unnecessarily.

Have you considered calling the same script for both (`./scripts/docker-publish-travis.sh`), and have this script do something else based on the `$TRAVIS_BRANCH` environment variable (or [any other](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#default-environment-variables))?

```
if [[ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" == "master" ]]; then
  # Publish production here
else
  # Publish develop here
fi
```

Comment: Thank you, your approach is simpler and I like simple.